# Layout with sliding panel in Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-viewpager

How to achieve this behavior:
[image]

When trying to scroll ListView up, ViewPager goes to the top of the screen and covers the view on the top (top view remains on the same place with same size). And after ViewPager riches the top ListView starts scrolling. In case you swipe down ListView scrolls until it reaches first element in the list and then ViewPager goes down until top view fully reveals.

Layouts? Event listeners?

Comment: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: okay. But I can't figure out how to make it work with ListView. Because in case of up scroll it should slide the panel up at first and then scroll list view, in case of down scroll it should scroll list view to the first item and then slide down the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScrollView and inside that you can put your list view. Scrool view will provide you scrolling facility and inside that your list will be there. like below

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">



    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

[CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) lets you do exactly that. It allows one view to "react" to another sibling view's "scrolling".

Also look into CollapsibleToolbarLayout and/or AppBarLayout.

The link Denis poster is also helpful.